# Fill matrix with column values in R using colnames and rownames

Tags: r, matrix

I have a very large dataset, so I want to avoid loops.

I have three columns of data:

> col1 = time presented as 10000, 10001, 10002, 10100, 10101, 10102,
>   10200, 10201, 10202, 10300, ... (total 18000 times)
>
> col2 = id number 1 2 3 4 ... (total 500 ids)
>
> col3 = reading associated with particular id at particular time. 0.1
>   0.5 0.6 0.7... Say this is called Data3
>
> 10000  1   0.1
>
> 10001  1   0.5
>
> 10002  1   0.6
>
> 10100  1   0.7
>
> 10200  1   0.6  (NOTE - some random entries missing)

I want to present this as a matrix (called DataMatrix), but there is missing data, so a simple reshape will not do. I want to have the missing data as NA entries.

DataMatrix is currently an NA matrix of 500 columns and 18000 rows, where the row names and column names are the times and ids respectively.

> 1   2   3   4  ....
>
> 10000  NA  NA  NA  NA ....
>
> 10001  NA  NA  NA  NA ....

Is there a way I can get R to go through each row of Data3, completing DataMatrix with the reading Data3[,3] by placing it in the row and column of the matrix whose names relate to the Data3[,1] and Data3[,2]. But without loops.

Thanks to all you smart people out there.

Comment: Why do you say "there is missing data, so a simple reshape will not do"? Did you try it? What did not work about the solution? If you provide a (small) reproducible example that demonstrates the conditions/problems you expect to run into, you're more likely to get meaningful help.

Comment: What about `library(reshape2); DataMatrix <- dcast(Data3, col1~col2, value.var="col3")`?

Comment: Thanks Ananda - you're right - playing around is definitely the way forward. I thought there might be some matching or look up function which I didn't know about. 

The missing data means that Data3 is NOT 18000*500 long, but less. Hence, reshaping disaster.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly:

```
Data3 <- data.frame(col1=10000:10499,  
                    col2=1:500,
                    col3=round(runif(500),1))

library(reshape2) 
DataMatrix <- dcast(Data3, col1~col2, value.var="col3")
DataMatrix[1:5, 1:5]
#    col1   1   2   3   4
# 1 10000 0.4  NA  NA  NA
# 2 10001  NA 0.6  NA  NA
# 3 10002  NA  NA 0.9  NA
# 4 10003  NA  NA  NA 0.5
# 5 10004  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: This may not work completely if your data doesn't have all the possible col1 and col2 values, I think.  It will if it does.

Comment: Thanks for this LukeA and BrodieG. I'm trying it out now and pretty excited! Fingers crossed :)

Comment: This is friggin' awesome! Thanks so much you wonderful starry stars!! ****

Comment: @user3173922, you should mark the answer that works for you as answered. tx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with possible id values in 1:10 and times values in 1:20.  First, create data:

```
mx <- matrix(c(sample(1:20, 5), sample(1:10, 5), sample(1:50, 5)), ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, c("time", "id", "reading")))
times <- 1:20
ids <- 1:10
mx
#      time id reading
# [1,]    4  3      25
# [2,]    5  4       9
# [3,]    9  7      45
# [4,]   18  1      40
# [5,]   11  8      28
```

Now, use `outer` to pass every possible combination of time/id to a look up function that returns the corresponding `reading` value:

```
outer(times, ids, 
  function(x, y) {
    mapply(function(x.sub, y.sub) {
      val <- mx[mx[, 1] == x.sub & mx[, 2] == y.sub, 3]
      if(length(val) == 0L) NA_integer_ else val
    },
    x, y)
} )
```

This produces the (hopefully) desired answer:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
#  [2,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
#  [3,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
#  [4,] NA   NA   25   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
#  [5,] NA   NA   NA   9    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
#  [6,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
#  [7,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
#  [8,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
#  [9,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   45   NA   NA   NA   
# [10,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
# [11,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   28   NA   NA   
# [12,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
# [13,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
# [14,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
# [15,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
# [16,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
# [17,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
# [18,] 40   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
# [19,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   
# [20,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```